# Backup procedure for SQL Server + S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup-strategies

I have a simple document management system which uses:

- SQL Server database
- S3 bucket as the files repository

How would you implement a backup process?

I know how to backup the database, 
and I suppose there is an option to backup the files to Glacier.

But how do I do this simultaneously so that I can restore both?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SQL Server on your own instance, or using RDS?

Comment: my own instance